# How do I find point B of line AB with only point A, distance, and slope?

Tags: trigonometry, slope

Good morning. There is a line AB and A is at point (x, y). x and y are known. So is the slope (m) and distance (time).

Is there a formula to calculate the x and y value separately of point B?

Comment: Solve for $~(x_1, y_1)~$ via [1] $~(x - x_1)^2 + (y - y_1)^2 = D^2~$ and [2] $~(y - y_1) = M(x - x_1).$  You will get two equations in two unknowns, which should have two solutions.  Geometrically, this makes sense, because the line passing through $(x,y)$ with the given slope can be extended in both directions.

Comment: The issue of whether the result is one answer rather than two answers revolves around how the *time/distance* constraint is interpreted.  If (for example), motion (up and to the right) is interpreted as a positive motion, and the time given is positive (rather than the absolute value of the distance), then you have only one solution, rather than two solutions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe time is straightforward and B is later then A.

Then $$x_B=x_A+ distance \cdot \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+slope^2}}$$
$$y_B=y_A + distance \cdot \frac{slope}{\sqrt{1+slope^2}}$$

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I entirely understand what you're asking. But I think you get a right triangle where you know the ratio of the leg lengths (via the slope) and the length of the hypotenuse ("distance"). You should be able to find any remaining parts based on this information and the Pythagorean Theorem. On the other hand, if "distance" refers to change in just $x$, then you know a leg and the ratio of the legs, and again you can proceed from there.

Once you have the values for the two legs, you should be able to find point $B$.

Comment: This should result in two distinct answers.  See my comment, following the question.

Comment: No. Once you have point B correctly, distance will be the distance from A to B using pythagorean theorem. Thank you for your help.